# Can Laravel page content tests be constrained by a CSS or XPath expression?

Tags: php, laravel, functional-testing

I'm learning Laravel and am currently looking at how automated functional tests should be written. I'm used to tools like Selenium and [Spiderling](https://github.com/OpenBuildings/phpunit-spiderling), where I can specify where on a page a text fragment should be found.

For example, in Spiderling, I can do this:

```
$page = $this->visit(self::DOMAIN . '/browse');
$firstSource = $page->
    find('table#reports tbody tr:first-child td:last-child')->
    text();
$this->assertEquals('Item 1', $firstSource);
```

That's pretty explicit: the text "Item 1" must be in the first row of the `reports` table, in the last cell.

As I understand it from [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing), to check for a text fragment in Laravel, one can do this:

```
$this->
    visit('/browse')->
    see('Item 1');
```

However, to me that is not very satisfying - how can I guard against a regression error that gets the text right but the placement wrong? I'd be happy to use either CSS or XPath here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is nice and easy, just not documented. In the `InteractsWithPages` trait there's a method `seeInElement`:

```
$this->
    visit('/browse')->
    seeInElement('table#reports tbody tr:first-child td:last-child', 'Item 1');
```